# Functional dependency of multiple types

Tags: haskell, functional-dependencies

Is the following possible (in spirit) with the GHC?

```
-- Syntax error: parse error on input `a'
class Foo a b c | (a, b) -> c where
  foo :: a -> b -> c
```

What alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`class Foo a b c | a b -> c` should work fine; it's the same syntax on the right-hand side, too.

`as -> bs` simply means that *as* collectively determines every *bs*.